# I Want to show the alert of fetched row from database table on body load event

Tags: php

I want to compare current system date with my database table date as shown. If both matched then corresponding member Name will be shown in alert on body load.

**My Code**

```
<?php 
    $now=date("Y/m/d"); 
    $sql = "select MemName from payment where $now ='$RemindDate' "; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($rowval2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $MemName=$rowval2['MemName']); 
    } 
    alert("$rowval2['MemName']"); 
?>
```

Comment: Please show some your work. What you have done yet .. ??

Comment: <?php
$now=date("Y/m/d");
$sql = "select MemName from payment where $now ='$RemindDate' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($rowval2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$MemName=$rowval2['MemName']); 
}
alert("$rowval2['MemName']");
?>

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the date from database table then compare with your system date using date()[Ref.1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)  [Ref.2](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp) 
if the date match then use member id to fetch member name and display it using alert().

```
 <?php 

    $now=date("Y/m/d"); 
    $sql = "select MemName from payment where date_column_name = '".$now."' "; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($rowval2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $MemName=$rowval2['MemName']; 
        } 

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert ('<?php echo $MemName; ?>')';
echo '</script>';

    ?>
```

Now the other option is, When you use JavaScript tag in echo function, It can be misleading because of "quotation" signs in php echo function. I suggest you to close tag if you are beginner.  Also try to echo each query and its result so you will get idea that it actually working or not.

```
<?php 

    $now=date("Y/m/d"); 
    $sql = "select MemName from payment where date_column_name = '".$now."' "; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($rowval2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $MemName=$rowval2['MemName']; 
        } 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     alert("<?php echo $MemName; ?>"); 
  </script>
<?php
?>
```

Comment: alert will not work directly in php code. you have to echo alert box also with javascript script tag. or simple alert ('<?php echo $phpvariable ?>');

Comment: 'alert ('<?php echo $MemName; ?>')';......if i place this alert like this,,,its showing error of syntax..unexpected ?......what should i do ..

Comment: Check updated answer .. make some changes with quotations . actually I didn't check your code. so make changes as per errors.

Comment: i did as u told me.but now its showing a blank page with no error and no alert.

Comment: check you table column that it store date in same manner as date() shows output. If you have stored time in column then it wont match with current sql query. For that u will have to use "LIKE" clause or Regexp. otherwise store date using date function. so it will match with this query.

Comment: thankew...now its working..but now i have to work on cases...i am working on payment remainder method alert on load of body.